# Получение значения из атрибута

Tags: javascript, html, атрибуты

```html
<span class="murr" onclick="form();" info="{"firstID":"0101017","line":"","22":""}">Атрибут</span>
```

Реально ли с помощью JS вытащить (получить) значение (0101017) атрибута info?

Получаю все значение:

```js
document.querySelector("#span.murr").getAttribute('info')
```

Может как то отфильтровать можно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если взять значение атрибута `info` в одинарные кавычки:

```
info='{"firstID":"0101017","line":"","22":""}'
```

то оно будет представлять корректную JSON-строку. И её можно легко преобразовать в объект.

```js
let attribute = document.querySelector("span.murr").getAttribute("info");
let obj = JSON.parse(attribute);

for (let elem of Object.entries(obj))
console.log(elem[0] + " : " + elem[1]);

console.log(obj.firstID);
```

```html
<span class="murr" info='{"firstID":"0101017","line":"","22":""}'>Атрибут</span>
```